# __builtin_clz returns incorrect value for input zero

Tags: c, gcc

I'm using the function `__builtin_clz` provided by GCC, which should count the number of leading zero bits in an `unsigned int`. But `__builtin_clz` returns an incorrect value for input `0`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  unsigned int x = 0;
  int lz = __builtin_clz(x);
  printf("%d\n", lz);
  return 1;
}
```

I expect this to print `32` on my machine. Instead, it prints `4195634`:

```
$ gcc -Wall clz.c
$ ./a.out
4195634
```

Is this my fault? Have I invoked some undefined behavior somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this my fault? Have I invoked some undefined behavior somewhere?

Yes, by passing 0 to `__builtin_clz`. From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html):

> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in x, starting at the most
>   significant bit position. **If x is 0, the result is undefined**.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that! Thanks. A pretty unintuitive behavior IMO ...

Comment: @jameshfisher - Perhaps. But it's probably for ease of implementation. And besides, you can always test for 0 explicitly and take `sizeof(unsigned) * CHAR_BIT` as the answer.

Comment: Indeed - I looked at the implementation, which uses the `bsr` instruction, which has the same undefined behavior when given 0.